# Rest API Authorization

Tags: rest-api, authentication

We're trying to use the JSforce library (http://jsforce.github.io/) for javascript access to the salesforce api but we keep getting "invalid_grant" errors when trying to authenticate

```
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.1.2/jsforce.min.js"></script>

<script>
        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
          oauth2 : {
            clientId : CLIENTID,
            clientSecret : CLIENTSECRET,
            redirectUri : REDIRECTURI,
            instanceUrl : 'http://test.salesforce.com'


          },

        });
        conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD, function(err, res) {
          if (err) { return console.error(err); }
          conn.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account', function(err, res) {
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            console.log(res);
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Even trying to do a simple curl request and we are still getting invalid grant

```
curl https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=CLIENTID" -d "client_secret=SECRET" -d "username=USERNAME" -d "password=PASSWORD"
```

We triple checked all the logins and ids and everything is correct?  any ideas?

Comment: I noticed you are sending the CURL request to test.salesforce.com. I assume you are using credentials that will work in a sandbox? You also require the SecurityToken appended to the password unless you are a trusted IP.